# what is this cookie (_op_aixPageId) i see it on many websites

Tags: javascript, html, security, cookies, web

hi recently we were scanning our website to comply with PCI standards a we found that there is an unsecured cookie created by our domain. we search our whole code base but didn't find any reference to a cookie named (_op_aixPageId).
also found this on internet search -- https://tools.digitalpoint.com/cookie-search?name=_op_aixPageId
many sites have this cookie on their domains.

what this cookie actually is and what tool is generating it?
any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The _op_aixPageId cookie is part of the riverbed AppInternals software formerly known as OPNET AppInternals.

For additional details, see:
http://dieball.net/2014/06/steelcentral-appinternals-browsermetrix-plugin-missing-features/